# Why is MarkLogic snippet resolution time so much longer for an end date than a start date range index comparison?

Tags: marklogic

I have a combined query that uses a full text string query over a set of terms in conjunction with a structured query for a datetime index for the faceted term "create-date" where the filter can be applied against start-date and/or an end-date. If using the start date for comparison, e.g., 'start-date <= create-date', then the snippet resolution time is between 7-8 sec, but using the end-date comparison, e.g.,  'create-date <= end-date', then the snippet resolution time is over 6 minutes, even if the start-date filter is also applied.

Could this be affected by faceted constraints consisting of buckets of time ranges, or, because the create-date is a facet that includes a disproportionate number of create-date range index frequencies? But if so, why is the problem related to an end-date comparison filter?

I'm having difficulty figuring out how the faceted snippets and/or highlighting is actually implemented in the code. It uses a RestAPI approach to build the query.

Comment: Rather than dealing with combined query, facets and snippeting, have you tested with cts:range-query to only compare the two date range cases?

Comment: Yes - please note that the plan shows the problem with the snippet resolution time

Comment: So essentially the problem is that cts:range-query([index], ">=", [date]) is somehow much faster than cts:range-query([index], "<=", [date])?

Comment: If that were the case, I would have been able to solve this a long time ago. This issue has to do with snippet resolution time and or highlighting or date time values in the search results, the use of facets, and the prolonged time when the <- operation is in place in the context of a combined query using the Rest API. So what I want to experiment with is disabling snippet resolution of the datetime field and perhaps to change it to not be a facet.

Comment: If it is not an easily isolable technical issue, I guess SO may not be the best place to address it. You may need to file a support ticket with the vendor.